# Redirecionar para uma página se e-mail estiver errado e outra se certo

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Boa noite. Preciso criar um form que o e-mail possa ser preenchido com um e-mail valido e senha (leva a uma página) ou com um nome sem @ e sem senha (leva a outra página). É possível fazer isso? No momento tenho esse código que direciona ambas as opções para a mesma página.

```
<div id="login">
    <span>Acesso Cond&ocirc;mino</span>




<form target="_blank" name="form1" method="post" action="http://sistema.ajmcondominios.com.br">

      <input type="hidden" value="logar" name="action"/>
      <input id="cod" type="hidden" value="845" name="cod"/>


 <label>Login:
<input type="text"  name="login" id="nome" value="" placeholder="Digite seu Login..." required/></label>
<label style="margin-left:30px;">Senha:
<input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" value="" placeholder="Digite sua senha..." /></label>
<label style="margin-left:30px;margin-top:30px;">
<button name="Submit" type="submit" value=“” style=“medium”>OK</button></label>
    </form>
</div><!--fim login-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, você pode chamar o `action` no script de acordo com a condição. Criei um *event handler* para pegar o `submit` do formulário:

> Recomendo usar `type="email"` no campo de e-mail pois assim o
>   `required` irá exigir que haja ao menos um `@`.

```
document.form1.addEventListener("submit", function(){
   if(this.login.value.indexOf("@") == -1 || !this.senha.value){
     // página com erro, email sem @ OU campo senha vazio
     document.form1.action = "pagina1.php"; 
   }else{
     document.form1.action = "pagina2.php"; 
   }
});
```

Agora, apague o atributo `action` do `<form>`:

```
<form target="_blank" name="form1" method="post">
```

**EDIT**

Se você quiser mesmo validar o email, pode usar esta função:

```
function checkMail(email){
    invalidChars = " ~\'^\`\"*+=\\|][(){}$&!%/:,;ç";

    if (email == "") {
        return false;
    }

    for (i=0; i<invalidChars.length; i++) {
        badChar = invalidChars.charAt(i);
        if (email.indexOf(badChar,0) > -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    lengthOfEmail = email.length;
    if ((email.charAt(lengthOfEmail - 1) == ".") || (email.charAt(lengthOfEmail - 2) == ".")) {
        return false;
    }

    Pos = email.indexOf("@",1);
    if (email.charAt(Pos + 1) == ".") {
        return false;
    }

    while ((Pos < lengthOfEmail) && ( Pos != -1)) {
        Pos = email.indexOf(".",Pos);
        if (email.charAt(Pos + 1) == ".") {
            return false;
        }
        if (Pos != -1) {
            Pos++;
        }
    }

    atPos = email.indexOf("@",1);
    if (atPos == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    if (email.indexOf("@",atPos+1) != -1) {
        return false;
    }

    periodPos = email.indexOf(".",atPos);
    if (periodPos == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    if (periodPos+3 > email.length) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Neste caso o código ficaria assim:

```
document.form1.addEventListener("submit", function(){
   if(!checkMail(this.login.value) || !this.senha.value){
     // página com erro, email inválido OU campo senha vazio
     document.form1.action = "pagina1.php"; 
   }else{
     document.form1.action = "pagina2.php"; 
   }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, funcionou perfeitamente.